# How to install the 2014 NTP security fix on 10.6.8 Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, security, ntp

For 10.6.8 would it work to open the 10.8 NTP update.dmg with pacifist and put in the new versions of the following 6 files?:

```
/usr/bin/sntp  
/usr/bin/ntp-keygen  
/usr/bin/ntpq  
/usr/sbin/ntpdc  
/usr/sbin/ntpdate  
/usr/sbin/ntpd
```

I am not sure about including the `ntptrace` file that was in the 10.8 `sbin` directory. What does it do? Also what would the appropriate `chown` command be to get these files properly recognized?

Answer (score 2):

> For 10.6.8 would it work to open the 10.8 NTP update.dmg with pacifist and put in the new versions of the following 6 files?

No it would not work. You will probably get a segmentation fault due to major changes that happened between 10.6 and 10.8 (I don't think you could even make 10.8 binaries work on 10.7). You can easily try it, however, to convince yourself. Extract them with Pacifist to some temp directory and just run them (eg. extract ntpd and do a `./ntpd --version` ). If you don't get a segmentation fault and you get a printout of the version, you might be fine. However, there's a better option.

Instead of using Apple's binaries, you should compile NTP yourself. It's not difficult at all and it requires Xcode (which is free anyway).

See my answer to a similar question that was posted the other day on how to compile NTP: [Disabling NTP on OS X Lion or older](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/disabling-ntp-on-os-x-lion-or-older/163305)

Answer (score 1):

As MelB mentioned installing the 10.8 NTP update.dmg in Snow Leopard will not work.

But compiling it yourself is easy:

Prerequisites: XCode 3.2.6

- Get XCode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3

  To get XCode 3.2.6 register at [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com). You may sign in with an Apple ID and after hitting a lot of radio buttons you are in. Go to the downloads section and search for 'XCode 3.2.6' in the downloads section.
  Download 'xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg' (4.14 GB) and install it. You don't have to install the iOS part.
- Open Terminal.app
- Copy the text below with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but don't paste it anywhere or copy anything else before you finished the next step:

  ```
  $ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.ntp.ntpd.plist
  $ sudo cp /usr/sbin/ntpd /usr/sbin/ntpd.old
  $ sudo cp /usr/sbin/ntpdate /usr/sbin/ntpdate.old
  $ sudo cp /usr/sbin/ntpdc /usr/sbin/ntpdc.old
  $ sudo cp /usr/sbin/ntptrace /usr/sbin/ntptrace.old
  $ sudo cp /usr/bin/sntp /usr/bin/sntp.old
  $ sudo cp /usr/bin/ntp-keygen /usr/bin/ntp-keygen.old
  $ sudo cp /usr/bin/ntpq /usr/bin/ntpq.old
  $ mkdir ntpd-fix
  $ cd ntpd-fix
  $ curl http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~ntp/ntp_spool/ntp4/ntp-4.2/ntp-4.2.8.tar.gz | tar zxf -
  $ cd ntp-4.2.8/ntpd
  $ curl http://bugs.ntp.org/attachment.cgi?id=1165 | patch -p1
  $ cd ..
  $ ./configure --prefix='/usr' && make && sudo make install
  $ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.ntp.ntpd.plist
  $ rm -r ~/ntpd-fix
  ```

  - Line 1 unloads ntpd
  - Lines 2-8 backup your old ntp*-files
  - Lines 9 and 10 create a folder ntpd-fix in your User folder and change your working directory
  - Lines 11-13 download, unarchive the ntpd sources and apply a necessary patch
  - Lines 14 and 15 change your working directory, compile and install all necessary files.
  - Line 16 reloads ntpd
  - Line 17 removes the folder ntpd-fix
- then immediately enter manually (don't copy and paste this!) in Terminal:

  ```
  pbpaste | cut -c 2- | sh
  ```

  and hit <kbd>⏎</kbd>, enter your admin password and wait a few minutes.

  - this pipes the pasteboard to `cut` which pipes single lines to your `shell` which then will be executed one by one.
- Result:

  updated `*ntp*-files`
  your old `*ntp*.old-files`

  and some new files and folders:
  `/usr/sbin/ntp-wait`
  `/usr/sbin/ntpsnmpd`
  `/usr/share/doc/ntp4` with html-help-files and one subfolder with some more html-help-files.

If you run into problems with the new ntpd check the manual: `/usr/share/doc/ntp4`

If you want to revert to your old files, sudo remove:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpd  
/usr/sbin/ntpdate  
/usr/sbin/ntpdc 
/usr/sbin/ntptrace 
/usr/bin/sntp 
/usr/bin/ntp-keygen 
/usr/bin/ntpq  
/usr/sbin/ntp-wait  
/usr/sbin/ntpsnmpd  
/usr/share/doc/ntp4
```

and sudo rename the `*old-files` by removing `.old`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned elsewhere in answers, you can't take the compiled NTP binaries from 10.8 and try to use them on 10.6. You would need versions compiled on 10.6.

Other answers mentioned how to compile them.  It requires downloading the source code, the patch, and having Xcode installed.

If you want to save a few steps, compiled patched versions of the files for 10.6.8 can be found here:
https://github.com/MacMiniVault/NTPUpdateSnowLeopard/tree/master/usr

If you want a quick installer, they're packaged up for an easy install here:
https://github.com/MacMiniVault/NTPUpdateSnowLeopard/releases

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have SL 10.8 installed on your mac, then download and install
   xcode version 3.2 for SL 785.1MB. it works.
2. Open a terminal window then copy and paste this: `pbpaste | cut -c 2-
   | sh`, then type this in the same terminal window: `clear` (you have
   cleared the window).

After that copy all this lines but DON´T PASTE ANYTHING YET (this is step 3):

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.ntp.ntpd.plist
sudo cp /usr/sbin/ntpd /usr/sbin/ntpd.old
sudo cp /usr/sbin/ntpdate /usr/sbin/ntpdate.old
sudo cp /usr/sbin/ntpdc /usr/sbin/ntpdc.old
sudo cp /usr/sbin/ntptrace /usr/sbin/ntptrace.old
sudo cp /usr/bin/sntp /usr/bin/sntp.old
sudo cp /usr/bin/ntp-keygen /usr/bin/ntp-keygen.old
sudo cp /usr/bin/ntpq /usr/bin/ntpq.old
mkdir ntpd-fix
cd ntpd-fix  
curl http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~ntp/ntp_spool/ntp4/ntp-4.2/ntp-4.2.8.tar.gz | tar zxf -  
cd ntp-4.2.8/ntpd
curl http://bugs.ntp.org/attachment.cgi?id=1165 | patch -p1
cd ..
./configure --prefix='/usr' && make && sudo make install
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.ntp.ntpd.plist
rm -r ~/ntpd-fix
```

Press the arrow keys: up and down till you find this command in the terminal 
window: `pbpaste | cut -c 2- | sh`

Once you have found the above mentioned command then press enter. You will see all the text you copied in step 3 appears in the terminal window.
Finally press enter. If the system request your admin password. Type it 
just wait till all the patching process concludes (takes some time) 
when the system ends compiling and patching just verify your ntp version 
copy and paste this in a terminal window:

```
ntpd --version
```

You have to see this:

```
ntpd 4.2.8@1.3265-o
```

Process finished.

Answer (score -2):

A more straightforward approach is here...been out for a while, and uses far fewer commands and steps: http://www.macissues.com/2014/12/24/how-to-manually-patch-ntp-for-os-x-10-6-and-10-7/